# Automate 1GP Managed Package Uninstallation (Remove dependencies via Apex Script or anything)

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api

Good day all!

I've a 1GP Managed package installed in my org. So, naturally, I'm using several components from the package in my org. However, whenever I want to uninstall it(scenarios where I must uninstall) every time, there are many dependencies. I've to do some manual steps to remove the dependencies. Those are mentioned below:

- Page Layout: I must manually unassign package ones to remove dependencies.
- Approval Process: Need to remove email templates.
- Flow: Need to deactivate.
- Process builder: Need to deactivate.

So, it's time-consuming! What I intend to do is write an Apex Script and run it. The script will remove all the dependencies so I can uninstall it in seconds.
My question is, is there anything like this?

- I've recently learned about the Apex Metadata API, but I'm not sure if it applies to my scenario.
- Also, I'm wondering if it's possible to deploy Metadata from VSCode to manage the layout or other assignments.

Thank you!